# Django model filter, reduce number of queries

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model called ListItem, which I break down into its types for the template as so:

```
list_items = ListItem.objects.filter(list__user=request.user.id)
type2list_items = list_item.filter(list__type=1)
type3list_items = list_item.filter(list__type=2)
```

This ends up creating too many queries, how can I make it just one? Which I can then filter into the bottom 2 vars without hitting the database again? Thanks

Comment: AFAIK, the first filter will not hit db, but the last two will.

Comment: @杨扬-momo yes, i'd like one query to put all the records into list_items then a way to filter them into the other two without another query. (as you can do in raw sql)

Comment: You can always pull all results from your first filter into a list, and then filter in Python using the [`filter` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter). You might need to add a `.select_related('list')` to your filter, in order to avoid additional queries when accessing each item's `list` field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) for queries like this.

```
from django.db.models import Q

    list_items = ListItem.objects.filter(Q(list__type=1) |
                           Q(list__type=2)).filter(list__user=request.user.id)
```